# classification table select statement

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, classification

I am developing a soccer league, in which team are randomly done by computer.
This league ranks players instead of teams.
Each player scores depending on the outcome of the game:

```
his team wins : player scores 3 point
his team wins >5 goals difference: player scores 4 points
his team draws: player scores 1 point
his team loses: player doesnt score
```

To store league data, I created these tables in mySQL InnoDB:

```
game (id)
player (num, name)
team (game.id, player.num, type)
goals (time, team.id, team.num, team.type)
```

type - identifies which team is the player (CHAR "A" or "B")

- I would like to retrieve classification based on rules above, how should I compose the Query in mySQL?
- I am avoiding to store data that could be calculated (good practice), but should I change table structure?

Answer (score 0):

```
SUM(CASE WHEN a THEN 3
         WHEN b THEN 4
         WHEN c THEN 5
         WHEN d THEN 1
                ELSE 0 END) ttl
```